# Ink Annotation not included in PDF, generated using Syncfusion

Tags: pdf, annotations, pdf-generation, syncfusion, wordtopdf

I have a word file that needs to be converted to PDF.
I have used Syncfusion DocIORenderer library to do the same.

If the file contains Ink Annotations then those annotations are not included in the generated PDF.

Original Word Document
[image: Word Document with Ink Annotation]

Generated PDF Document
[image: Generated PDF Document]

**How to include ink annotations in the PDF using Syncfusion libraries.**

Answer (score 0):

Syncfusion Word Library (DocIO) currently does not support ink annotation in a Word document. We have already logged a feature request, “**Support for ink in DOCX format document**” in our database. We don’t have any immediate plans to implement this feature. We will let you know once the feature is implemented.

The status of this feature report can be tracked through the below link:
https://www.syncfusion.com/feedback/40968/support-for-ink-in-docx-format-document